# Joomla style back end editing in the front-end

Tags: joomla

I have a Joomla component where users will be able to create lists, however, I need to display this is the front end.  How do I go about displaying a back-end component in the front-end?

Comment: Is this something you have built or downloaded from somewhere?

Comment: this is something I have built

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend code is stored in administrator/components/com_component/...

You need to create front end code to display your lists. This code should be kept in components/com_component/... You can probably copy most of the code and code structure for the back end but there are some changes that will need to be made.

So if the backend creates lists, then this must be stored in the db or in a text file at the very least. Then in the front end you need to access this data and then display it.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.joomladevuser.com/tutorials/components) on how to create Joomla components, which may help you get started in developing the front end to display the lists as you require.

Comment: So is it possible to display the backend Toolbar and such in the frontend?

Comment: If you want to use the toolbar in the frontend then you need to look at this tutorial - http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_the_JToolBar_class_in_the_frontend

Answer (score 0):

If this is a component that was not designed to allow for front end editing then there is a way to do it without having to hack the component or write any code. You can design a form that matches up with the database table you are going to be working on using ChronoForms. Then connect the form to the database table using ChronoConnectivity. This will allow you to display, edit, delete, or insert records in to the database. There are some pretty good tutorials on how to do this on the Vhrono forums.

Forums - http://football.fantasysports.yahoo.com/f1/131438
Downloads - http://www.chronoengine.com/downloads.html